# Search in Class Based ListView | Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to search items in cbv. Though it's too easy with `function based views` but I don't know how to use it in CBV.

I tried like this

**views.py**

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item

    #query = request.GET.get("q")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            context['model'] = Item.objects.get(title=query)
            print(query)
        return context

    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = "home.html"
```

**home.html**

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="">
 <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
</form>
```

The problem is it's showing all items( not specifically searched items ).
Example:
in url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=Blue` it is not only showing the item with `Blue` title but all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) to filter the objects:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            return qs.filter(title=query)
        return qs
```

This queryset will then be paginated as well. So that means that in this case, it will show the first five matches.